# How to rearrange/reorder the rows and columns in python dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

[SCREEN SHOT OF ACTUAL DATA FRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TWVn.png)**Dataframe of 5000 rows and 192 columns**

I want to change the size of my data frame of m rows and n columns (m= 5000 and n = 192) into a size of n/3 rows(64 rows) and m*5000 columns(15000 columns)??

**existing data frame**

```
0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9.....A192
1 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9.....B192
.
.
.
5000 192 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9.....X192
```

**DESIRED data frame**

```
0 A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3.....X1 X2 X3
1 A4 A5 A6 B4 B5 B6.....X4 X5 X6
2 A7 A8 A9 B7 B8 B9.....X7 X8 X9
.
.
64 A190 A191 A192 B190 B191 B192.....X190 X191 X192
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, can use a loop

```
pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[:, e:e+3].values.flatten() for e in range(0, 192, 3)])
```

Comment: Perfect. Works well :)

Answer (score 1):

I will using `groupby`

```
pd.DataFrame([y.values.ravel()for x , y in df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//3,axis=1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x.ravel() for x in np.split(df.values,
                                              df.shape[1]//3, axis = 1)]))
```

Comment: I kind of tested it, it works for me just fine, even though I'm not sure what you mean by df_z

Answer (score 0):

```
np.concatenate([np.reshape(col,(64,3)) for col in data.T.values],axis=1)
```